# Popup Menu not appearing at my Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

There are TPopupMenu and three buttons on the form named "AddButton", "EditButton", and "DestroyButton" and added OnClick events to all three buttons. The TPopupMenu in the PopupMenu property of the form. I have created the PopupMenuItemsClick procedure in the TForm1 type declaration so that it can be used as the method call for the menu item OnClick event.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    AddButton: TButton;
    EditButton: TButton;
    DestroyButton: TButton;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    procedure AddButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EditButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DestroyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    procedure PopupMenuItemsClick(Sender: TObject);

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.AddButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  index: Integer;
  NewItem: TMenuItem;
begin
        // The owner (PopupMenu1) will clean up this menu item.
  NewItem := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu1); // Create the new item.
  index := PopupMenu1.Items.Count;
  PopupMenu1.Items.Add(NewItem);// Add it to the pop-up menu.
  NewItem.Caption := 'Menu Item ' + IntToStr(index);
  NewItem.Tag := index;
  NewItem.OnClick :=
    PopupMenuItemsClick; // Assign it an event handler.
end;

procedure TForm1.PopupMenuItemsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Sender as TMenuItem do
  begin
    case Tag of
      0:  ShowMessage('first item clicked');
      1:  ShowMessage('second item clicked');
      2:  ShowMessage('third item clicked');
      3:  ShowMessage('fourth item clicked');
    end;
  end;
end;

{
To edit or destroy an item, grab its pointer 
using the Items property.
procedure TForm1.EditButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ItemToEdit: TMenuItem;
begin
  ItemToEdit := PopupMenu.Items[1];
  ItemToEdit.Caption := 'Changed Caption';
end;

procedure TForm1.DestroyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ItemToDelete: TMenuItem;
begin
  ItemToDelete := PopupMenu.Items[2];
  ItemToDelete.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  index: Integer;
  NewItem: TMenuItem;
begin
  for index := 0 to 3 do
  begin
          // The owner (PopupMenu1) will clean up this menu item.
    NewItem := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu1); // Create the new item.
    PopupMenu1.Items.Add(NewItem);// Add it to the pop-up menu.
    NewItem.Caption := 'Menu Item ' + IntToStr(index);
    NewItem.Tag := index;
    NewItem.OnClick :=
      PopupMenuItemsClick; // Assign it an event handler.
  end;
end;
```

But PopupMenu is not appearing when I clicked on addmenu button. Anyone can find what is the reason why Popupmenu is not appearing when form is loaded or any button clicked.

Comment: If we're talking about a left click, then you need to call `PopupMenu1.Popup(X, Y);` method (where X and Y are the screen coordinates) from your `AddButtonClick` event method to invoke the menu to popup. In your code something [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/jfABbMND).

Comment: @bummi: it already is: "The TPopupMenu in the PopupMenu property of the form."

Comment: @RemyLebeau Where you can see that PopupMenu1 is set as form PopUpMenu? It is only declared.

Comment: @slotomo: as I said earlier, Ninad specifically stated in the question that the `TPopupMenu` is assigned to the form's `PopupMenu` property.

Answer (score 3):

your code not what you really need
use this code and it will work perfectly

```
procedure TForm1.PopupMenuItemsClick(Sender: TObject);
  var ICount : Integer;
begin
  ICount := TMenuItem(Sender).MenuIndex;
  ShowMessage('Item Number '+ IntToStr(ICount+1) + ' Selected');
end;

procedure TForm1.AddClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    Index: Integer;
    NewItem: TMenuItem;
begin
    NewItem := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu);
    Index := PopupMenu.Items.Count;
    PopupMenu.Items.Add(NewItem);
    NewItem.Caption := 'Menu Item ' + IntToStr(Index);
    NewItem.Tag := Index;
    NewItem.OnClick := PopupMenuItemsClick;
    PopupMenu.Popup(Mouse.CursorPos.X, Mouse.CursorPos.Y);
end;
```

I tested it with Delphi7, XE2 and XE3 its working

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in the FormCreate or set this property in Object Inspector.
    `self.PopupMenu:=PopupMenu1;`

Comment: The same code works in xe-3, so this problem is only in xe-2.

Answer (score 0):

This comments may help to solve the problem (i was having similar in old Delphi versions, i do not have XE to test on).

- Never, ever create a component and let empty its `.Name`, allways
  assign it a unique value (i see a lot of faulty interna code when let empty, since they can not be empty).
- And allways assign properties and events to the componet prior to add
  them onto their parent.

See this suggestions in the comments:

```
procedure TForm1.AddClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    Index: Integer;
    NewItem: TMenuItem;
begin
    NewItem := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu);
    Index := PopupMenu.Items.Count;

    //PopupMenu.Items.Add(NewItem); // Not the correct place, see below
    NewItem.Name : = 'SomeText' + IntToStr(Index); // Name them, with a unique name not starting with a number (also there is no need to put a number)

    NewItem.Caption := 'Menu Item ' + IntToStr(Index);
    NewItem.Tag := Index;
    NewItem.OnClick := PopupMenuItemsClick;

    PopupMenu.Items.Add(NewItem); // After properties has been set, never before

    PopupMenu.Popup(Mouse.CursorPos.X, Mouse.CursorPos.Y);
    // Do not forget to free such menu item somewhere on your code, obviously not here
end;
```

And with menus, remember to free the items created, they do not free by them selfs and names will be in use next time.

Comment: Menu items will be freed by the menu itself. No need to free them. Also, Why do you think naming a component is mandatory?